# How to navigate to next item in sqlite database table - android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am developing a song book app and I have the following files:

1. SbDatabase.java for creating a database
2. SbProvider.java for creating a provider service to access the song
3. Searchable.java for searching the for songs
4. Song.java for showing one song that is picked from a listview of results

I need help to create an action that would allow a user switch to another song either ahead of before the current song being viewed. Here are my codes

1.SbDatabase.java

```
public class SbDatabase {
private static final String TAG = "SbDatabase";
public static final String KEY_WORD = SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1;
public static final String KEY_SONGCONT = SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_2;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "songbook";
    private static final String FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE = "FTSsongbook";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    private final SongbookOpenHelper mDatabaseOpenHelper;
    private static final HashMap<String,String> mColumnMap = buildColumnMap();

    public SbDatabase(Context context) {
        mDatabaseOpenHelper = new SongbookOpenHelper(context);
    }

    private static HashMap<String,String> buildColumnMap() {
        HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
        map.put(KEY_WORD, KEY_WORD);
        map.put(KEY_SONGCONT, KEY_SONGCONT);
        map.put(BaseColumns._ID, "rowid AS " +
                BaseColumns._ID);
        map.put(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID, "rowid AS " +
                SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID);
        map.put(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID, "rowid AS " +
                SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID);
        return map;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a Cursor positioned at the song specified by rowId
     *
     * @param rowId id of song to retrieve
     * @param columns The columns to include, if null then all are included
     * @return Cursor positioned to matching song, or null if not found.
     */
    public Cursor getSong(String rowId, String[] columns) {
        String selection = "rowid = ?";
        String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {rowId};

        return query(selection, selectionArgs, columns);

        /* This builds a query that looks like:
         *     SELECT <columns> FROM <table> WHERE rowid = <rowId>
         */
    }

    /**
     * Returns a Cursor over all songs that match the given query
     *
     * @param query The string to search for
     * @param columns The columns to include, if null then all are included
     * @return Cursor over all songs that match, or null if none found.
     */
    public Cursor getSongMatches(String query, String[] columns) {
        String selection = KEY_WORD + " MATCH ?";
        String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {query+"*"};

        return query(selection, selectionArgs, columns);

        /* This builds a query that looks like:
         *     SELECT <columns> FROM <table> WHERE <KEY_WORD> MATCH 'query*'
         * which is an FTS3 search for the query text (plus a wildcard) inside the song column.
         *
         * - "rowid" is the unique id for all rows but we need this value for the "_id" column in
         *    order for the Adapters to work, so the columns need to make "_id" an alias for "rowid"
         * - "rowid" also needs to be used by the SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA alias in order
         *   for suggestions to carry the proper intent data.
         *   These aliases are defined in the SbProvider when queries are made.
         * - This can be revised to also search the songcont text with FTS3 by changing
         *   the selection clause to use FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE instead of KEY_WORD (to search across
         *   the entire table, but sorting the relevance could be difficult.
         */
    }

    /**
     * Performs a database query.
     * @param selection The selection clause
     * @param selectionArgs Selection arguments for "?" components in the selection
     * @param columns The columns to return
     * @return A Cursor over all rows matching the query
     */
    private Cursor query(String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String[] columns) {
        /* The SQLiteBuilder provides a map for all possible columns requested to
         * actual columns in the database, creating a simple column alias mechanism
         * by which the ContentProvider does not need to know the real column names
         */
        SQLiteQueryBuilder builder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        builder.setTables(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE);
        builder.setProjectionMap(mColumnMap);

        Cursor cursor = builder.query(mDatabaseOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(),
                columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);

        if (cursor == null) {
            return null;
        } else if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            cursor.close();
            return null;
        }
        return cursor;
    }


    /**
     * This creates/opens the database.
     */
    private static class SongbookOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        private final Context mHelperContext;
        private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

        /* Note that FTS3 does not support column constraints and thus, you cannot
         * declare a primary key. However, "rowid" is automatically used as a unique
         * identifier, so when making requests, we will use "_id" as an alias for "rowid"
         */
        private static final String FTS_TABLE_CREATE =
                    "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE +
                    " USING fts3 (" +
                    KEY_WORD + ", " +
                    KEY_SONGCONT + ");";

        SongbookOpenHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            mHelperContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            mDatabase = db;
            mDatabase.execSQL(FTS_TABLE_CREATE);
            loadSongbook();
        }

        /**
         * Starts a thread to load the database table with songs
         */
        private void loadSongbook() {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        loadSongs();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }

        private void loadSongs() throws IOException {
            Log.d(TAG, "Loading songs...");
            final Resources resources = mHelperContext.getResources();
            InputStream inputStream = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.songbook);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            try {
                String line;
                String thesong;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    thesong = line.replace("$", System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                    String[] strings = TextUtils.split(thesong, "%");
                    if (strings.length < 2) continue;
                    long id = addSong(strings[0].trim(), strings[1].trim());
                    if (id < 0) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "unable to add song: " + strings[0].trim());
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                reader.close();
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "DONE loading songs.");
        }

        public long addSong(String song, String songcont) {
            ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
            initialValues.put(KEY_WORD, song);
            initialValues.put(KEY_SONGCONT, songcont);

            return mDatabase.insert(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE, null, initialValues);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }
```

2. SbProvider.java

   ```
   public SbDatabase(Context context) {

       mDatabaseOpenHelper = new SongbookOpenHelper(context);
   }

   private static HashMap<String,String> buildColumnMap() {
       HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
       map.put(KEY_WORD, KEY_WORD);
       map.put(KEY_SONGCONT, KEY_SONGCONT);
       map.put(BaseColumns._ID, "rowid AS " +
               BaseColumns._ID);
       map.put(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID, "rowid AS " +
               SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID);
       map.put(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID, "rowid AS " +
               SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID);
       return map;
   }

   /**
    * Returns a Cursor positioned at the song specified by rowId
    *
    * @param rowId id of song to retrieve
    * @param columns The columns to include, if null then all are included
    * @return Cursor positioned to matching song, or null if not found.
    */
   public Cursor getSong(String rowId, String[] columns) {
       String selection = "rowid = ?";
       String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {rowId};

       return query(selection, selectionArgs, columns);

       /* This builds a query that looks like:
        *     SELECT <columns> FROM <table> WHERE rowid = <rowId>
        */
   }

   /**
    * Returns a Cursor over all songs that match the given query
    *
    * @param query The string to search for
    * @param columns The columns to include, if null then all are included
    * @return Cursor over all songs that match, or null if none found.
    */
   public Cursor getSongMatches(String query, String[] columns) {
       String selection = KEY_WORD + " MATCH ?";
       String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {query+"*"};

       return query(selection, selectionArgs, columns);

       /* This builds a query that looks like:
        *     SELECT <columns> FROM <table> WHERE <KEY_WORD> MATCH 'query*'
        * which is an FTS3 search for the query text (plus a wildcard) inside the song column.
        *
        * - "rowid" is the unique id for all rows but we need this value for the "_id" column in
        *    order for the Adapters to work, so the columns need to make "_id" an alias for "rowid"
        * - "rowid" also needs to be used by the SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA alias in order
        *   for suggestions to carry the proper intent data.
        *   These aliases are defined in the SbProvider when queries are made.
        * - This can be revised to also search the songcont text with FTS3 by changing
        *   the selection clause to use FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE instead of KEY_WORD (to search across
        *   the entire table, but sorting the relevance could be difficult.
        */
   }

   /**
    * Performs a database query.
    * @param selection The selection clause
    * @param selectionArgs Selection arguments for "?" components in the selection
    * @param columns The columns to return
    * @return A Cursor over all rows matching the query
    */
   private Cursor query(String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String[] columns) {
       /* The SQLiteBuilder provides a map for all possible columns requested to
        * actual columns in the database, creating a simple column alias mechanism
        * by which the ContentProvider does not need to know the real column names
        */
       SQLiteQueryBuilder builder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
       builder.setTables(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE);
       builder.setProjectionMap(mColumnMap);

       Cursor cursor = builder.query(mDatabaseOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(),
               columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);

       if (cursor == null) {
           return null;
       } else if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
           cursor.close();
           return null;
       }
       return cursor;
   }


   /**
    * This creates/opens the database.
    */
   private static class SongbookOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

       private final Context mHelperContext;
       private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

       /* Note that FTS3 does not support column constraints and thus, you cannot
        * declare a primary key. However, "rowid" is automatically used as a unique
        * identifier, so when making requests, we will use "_id" as an alias for "rowid"
        */
       private static final String FTS_TABLE_CREATE =
                   "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE +
                   " USING fts3 (" +
                   KEY_WORD + ", " +
                   KEY_SONGCONT + ");";

       SongbookOpenHelper(Context context) {
           super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
           mHelperContext = context;
       }

       @Override
       public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
           mDatabase = db;
           mDatabase.execSQL(FTS_TABLE_CREATE);
           loadSongbook();
       }

       /**
        * Starts a thread to load the database table with songs
        */
       private void loadSongbook() {
           new Thread(new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                   try {
                       loadSongs();
                   } catch (IOException e) {
                       throw new RuntimeException(e);
                   }
               }
           }).start();
       }

       private void loadSongs() throws IOException {
           Log.d(TAG, "Loading songs...");
           final Resources resources = mHelperContext.getResources();
           InputStream inputStream = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.songbook);
           BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

           try {
               String line;
               String thesong;
               while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                   thesong = line.replace("$", System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                   String[] strings = TextUtils.split(thesong, "%");
                   if (strings.length < 2) continue;
                   long id = addSong(strings[0].trim(), strings[1].trim());
                   if (id < 0) {
                       Log.e(TAG, "unable to add song: " + strings[0].trim());
                   }
               }
           } finally {
               reader.close();
           }
           Log.d(TAG, "DONE loading songs.");
       }

       public long addSong(String song, String songcont) {
           ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
           initialValues.put(KEY_WORD, song);
           initialValues.put(KEY_SONGCONT, songcont);

           return mDatabase.insert(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE, null, initialValues);
       }

       @Override
       public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
           Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                   + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
           db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE);
           onCreate(db);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Searchable.java

   public class Searchable extends ActionBarActivity {
       private TextView mTextView;
       private ListView mListView;
       LinearLayout MySong;

   ```
   @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.search);

       mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
       mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

       handleIntent(getIntent());

       Cursor cursor = managedQuery(SbProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
               new String[] {"Lotv"}, null);

       String[] from = new String[] { SbDatabase.KEY_WORD,
       SbDatabase.KEY_SONGCONT };

       int[] to = new int[] { R.id.song, R.id.songcont };

       SimpleCursorAdapter songs = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
              R.layout.result, cursor, from, to);
       mListView.setAdapter(songs);

       mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

           @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
           Intent songIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Song.class);
           Uri data = Uri.withAppendedPath(SbProvider.CONTENT_URI,
                                String.valueOf(id));
           songIntent.setData(data);
           startActivity(songIntent);
           }
       });

       mTextView.setText("568 Songs of Worship!");

   }

   @Override
   protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {     
       handleIntent(intent);
   }

   private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
       if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())) {
           Intent songIntent = new Intent(this, Song.class);
           songIntent.setData(intent.getData());
           startActivity(songIntent);
       } else if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
           String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
           showResults(query);
       }
   }

   private void showResults(String query) {

       Cursor cursor = managedQuery(SbProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
                               new String[] {query}, null);

       String[] from = new String[] { SbDatabase.KEY_WORD,
               SbDatabase.KEY_SONGCONT };

       int[] to = new int[] { R.id.song,
               R.id.songcont };

       SimpleCursorAdapter songs = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                      R.layout.result, cursor, from, to);
       mListView.setAdapter(songs);

       mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

           @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
           Intent songIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Song.class);
           Uri data = Uri.withAppendedPath(SbProvider.CONTENT_URI,
                                    String.valueOf(id));
           songIntent.setData(data);
           startActivity(songIntent);
               }
       });

       if (cursor == null) {
           mTextView.setText(getString(R.string.no_songs, new Object[] {query}));
       } else {
           int count = cursor.getCount();
           String countString = getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.search_results,
                                   count, new Object[] {count, query});
           mTextView.setText(countString);
             }

       }
   }
   ```

   }
4. Song.java is where I need you help to fix a button to allow a user go to another song on the ImageButton Next

   public class Song extends ActionBarActivity {

   ```
   RelativeLayout MySong;
   TextView songcont;
   private ImageButton Previous;
   private ImageButton Next;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.song);

   Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
   Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, null, null, null, null);

   if (cursor == null) {
       finish();
   } else {
       cursor.moveToFirst();

       TextView songcont = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songcont);
       songcont.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
       int wIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SbDatabase.KEY_WORD);
       int dIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SbDatabase.KEY_SONGCONT);
       setTitle(cursor.getString(wIndex));
       songcont.setText(cursor.getString(dIndex));
       Previous = (ImageButton)findViewById (R.id.imageButton1 );
       Next = (ImageButton)findViewById (R.id.imageButton2 ); 
       Next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

           public void onClick(View arg0) {

               Intent songIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Song.class);
               //Uri data = Uri.withAppendedPath(SbProvider.CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(id));
               Uri data = Uri.withAppendedPath(SbProvider.CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(id));

               songIntent.setData(data);
               startActivity(songIntent);
           }

       });
   } } }
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what worked for me:

```
public class Song extends ActionBarActivity {
    TextView songcont;
    private SbDatabase mSongbook;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.song);

    Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, null, null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();        
    TextView songcont = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songcont);
    songcont.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

    int wIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SbDatabase.KEY_WORD);
    int dIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SbDatabase.KEY_SONGCONT);

    String thetitle = (cursor.getString(wIndex));
    songcont.setText(cursor.getString(dIndex));
    setTitle(thetitle.replace("#", ""));

    Previous = (ImageButton)findViewById (R.id.imageButton1 );
    Previous.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
          Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, null, null, null, null);
          cursor.moveToFirst();                     
          int wIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SbDatabase.KEY_WORD);               

          String Title = (cursor.getString(wIndex));        
          String[] strings = TextUtils.split(Title, "#");
          String MyTitle = strings[0].trim();
          int id = Integer.parseInt(MyTitle);

          Uri data = Uri.withAppendedPath(SbProvider.CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(id-1));                
          Intent songIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Song.class);
          songIntent.setData(data);
          startActivity(songIntent);

        }

    });

    Next = (ImageButton)findViewById (R.id.imageButton2 ); 
    Next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
          Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, null, null, null, null);
          cursor.moveToFirst();                     
          int wIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SbDatabase.KEY_WORD);               

          String Title = (cursor.getString(wIndex));        
          String[] strings = TextUtils.split(Title, "#");
          String MyTitle = strings[0].trim();
          int id = Integer.parseInt(MyTitle);

          Uri data = Uri.withAppendedPath(SbProvider.CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(id+1));                
          Intent songIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Song.class);
          songIntent.setData(data);
          startActivity(songIntent);

        }

    });

    detector = new SimpleGestureFilter(this,this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code can work for you

```
public class Song extends ActionBarActivity {
    TextView songcont;
    private SbDatabase mSongbook;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.song);

    Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, null, null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();        
    TextView songcont = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songcont);
    songcont.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

    int wIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SbDatabase.KEY_WORD);
    int dIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SbDatabase.KEY_SONGCONT);

    String thetitle = (cursor.getString(wIndex));
    songcont.setText(cursor.getString(dIndex));
    setTitle(thetitle.replace("#", ""));

    Previous = (ImageButton)findViewById (R.id.imageButton1 );
    Previous.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
          Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, null, null, null, null);
          cursor.moveToFirst();                     
          int wIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SbDatabase.KEY_WORD);               

          String Title = (cursor.getString(wIndex));        
          String[] strings = TextUtils.split(Title, "#");
          String MyTitle = strings[0].trim();
          int id = Integer.parseInt(MyTitle);

          Uri data = Uri.withAppendedPath(SbProvider.CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(id-1));                
          Intent songIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Song.class);
          songIntent.setData(data);
          startActivity(songIntent);

        }

    });

    Next = (ImageButton)findViewById (R.id.imageButton2 ); 
    Next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
          Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, null, null, null, null);
          cursor.moveToFirst();                     
          int wIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SbDatabase.KEY_WORD);               

          String Title = (cursor.getString(wIndex));        
          String[] strings = TextUtils.split(Title, "#");
          String MyTitle = strings[0].trim();
          int id = Integer.parseInt(MyTitle);

          Uri data = Uri.withAppendedPath(SbProvider.CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(id+1));                
          Intent songIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Song.class);
          songIntent.setData(data);
          startActivity(songIntent);

        }

    });

    detector = new SimpleGestureFilter(this,this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Song  class add dowhile loop Then call moveToNext() to move next record in database .

do
{

} while (cur.moveToNext());

Comment: thanks but I could not implement that loop but check what worked for me